# Which sequences of integers admit an Euler Product?

Tags: analytic-number-theory, euler-product

Suppose that $A = \{a_n\}$ is an increasing sequence of positive integers and let $\zeta_A(s)=\sum_n \frac{1}{{a_n}^s}$.

For which sequences does $\zeta_A (s)=\prod_{p_{n_k}}(1-{p_{n_k}}^{-s})^{-1}$ for some infinite subset of the primes $\{p_{n_k}\}$?

Comment: Isn't this obvious? Just those sequences that are all numbers having a certain infinite subset $\{p_{n_k}\}$ as prime factors...

Comment: @mathworker21 your comment is not true.  It turns out that the Euler product formula holds only if A is a multiplicative semi-group.

Comment: The example I gave is a multiplicative semigroup